# host header change upstream servers nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-headers

I have following config in my config file

```
upstream static {
    server server1.dom.com; 
    server server2.dom.com;
} 
server  {
    listen 80;
    server name dom.com;
    location ^~ /images/ {
        proxy_pass  http://static/images/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|xls|flv)$ {
        root /var/www;
        expires 10d;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

How change it to see host headers of upstream servers in request headers.
Now i see only dom.com Host header in firebug.

Please help. :)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to clarify: you have `nginx` proxying requests from clients to that server on 127.0.0.1:8080, and you want _that_ server to see HTTP requests whose `Host` header contains the `Host` header as originally sent by the client?  Is that correct?